# How Monitor threadpool in grpc in JAVA?

Tags: java, grpc, threadpool

I have java grpc server and many user complain that thread pool is exhausted. I need to make something to monitor threads, how many thereads, how many in use, idle etc. Is there any way to do that.

Comment: May be this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687757/tools-to-monitor-java-thread-execution